# Lagrange Multiplier Method for box optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

A rectangular box with a square base and no top is to contain exactly 54 cubic centimeters. Find the dimensions that will yield the minimum cost if the base costs 4 times as much as the sides.

---

I am not sure how to apply Lagrange Multiplier Method to this problem as my teacher asked. I started with creating the function $C(s,h) = s^2 + 4hs$ for the cost of the box with base $s$ and height $h$. The restraint is $g(s,h) = s^2h = 54$. Is this the right setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  If the base sides have length s and the height is h, then the base has area $s^2$ and each side has area sh. There are 4 sides so the sides have total area 4sh. The surface area of the box is $s^2+ 4sh$.  However, you are not asked to minimize the surface area.  You are asked to minimize the **cost**.  Since the base cost four times as much as the sides, the cost will be $4s^2+ 4sh$.  The volume is $s^2h$ and the "constraint" is, as you say, $s^2h= 54$.